# dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required Error | Python

Tags: python

I am getting this error when trying to get info from a dictionary.

#1. What does this error mean?
#2. How would I go about fixing it

Here is my current code:

```
    getGroup = requests.get(url = "https://groups.roblox.com/v2/groups?groupIds=" + str(groupId))
    req = getGroup.text
    print(dict(req)["data"][0])
```

Error raised:

```
Command raised an exception: ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

The info the request gets:

```
{'data': [{'id': 7850173, 'name': 'Project Studios - Roblox', 'description': 'Happy May! \n\nJoin our Communications server to see the progress on our latest projects. \n\nCheck out my friends groups in the Affiliates tab! \n\nFunny Fortnite?\n\n- Group Description Updated 5-1-21 -', 'owner': {'id': 55065985, 'type': 'User'}, 'memberCount': 428, 'created': '2020-09-24T00:01:23.853Z'}]}
```

Thanks a lot if you could help!

Comment: `getGroup.text` gives you a string. There is not much point in turning a string to a dict. You will get the same error from `dict("bsdvdafsf")`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the json response into a data structure first.

```
getGroup = requests.get(url = "https://groups.roblox.com/v2/groups?groupIds=" + str(groupId))
req = getGroup.json()
await ctx.send(dict(req)["data"][0])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But I ran into one problem trying to get more information from the dict. I used await ctx.send(dict(req)["data"][0]["memberCount"][0]) but it didn't seem to work and raised the error: 'int' object is not subscriptable.

Comment: `req["data"][0]` correspond to the dict in the list, `req["data"][0]["memberCount"] `correspond to the element having memberCount as key so 428 which is an int and yes, you can't use [0] on an int